# why does Javascript getUserMedia only works with firefox?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble getting this code to work with browsers other than Firefox. The code is supposed to access the webcam. I can't find the problem. It does not work with chrome, internet explorer, Safari. It only works with Firefox. Does anyone have any answers why? How can I correct this code?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function loading()
{
 var video = document.querySelector('#forVid');
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;


   if (navigator.getUserMedia)
   {
     var thevid = {video: true, audio: false};
     navigator.getUserMedia(thevid, handleVideo, forError)
   }


function handleVideo(localmediastream)
   {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localmediastream);
   }

function forError(e)
    {
        // nothing
    }

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload = "loading()">

<video id = "forVid" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:50;"autoplay="true" height="600" width="600">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works for me in FF 34.0 and google chrome 41.0.2272.101

Comment: This should work in Chrome. How are you testing your code? Note that Chrome does not allow getUserMedia from file:// URLs while Firefox does. Use localhost or any number of sites like jsfiddle.net. The other browsers you mention don't support getUserMedia (yet).

Comment: That's why it's not working!!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Because this API has very less browser's support.
Following link lists all Supported and Unsupported browsers for this API.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

Answer (score 1):

BTW

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia says:

> Note: This is a legacy API for backwards compatibility. Please see navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia for modern applications.

So you'd better to use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` (also) in your code.

Comment: I have seen this code successfully implemented on other sites. For some reason, I have problems with it and the publishers of the site does not.

Comment: `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` is brand new, so please see the compatibility table on that page.